# GET request equivalente em arquivos separados (controller e route)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, passport-js

Boa noite!

To trabalhando num projeto, e na tela de login após realizar a autenticação(Passportjs), o usuário será redirecionado para a Home page.

Porém, a pouco tempo comecei a adotar alguns novos métodos para organizar melhor a estrutura do programa etc. E estou deixando um arquivo só para rotas (routes) e outro só pra gerenciar as chamadas GET, POST, DELETE, PATCH, PUT (controllers).

Antes de migrar os arquivos para esse novo formato, tudo funcionava normalmente...
Nesse trecho de código que estou com problemas...
Nesse formato funciona tudo normalmente

```js
app.get("/home", isAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render("home", {
      name: req.user.username
    });
  });
```

isAuth é um modulo para checar se o usuário está autenticado ou não, e caso esteja, será redirecionado.

```js
module.exports = {
  isAuth: (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    } else {
      req.flash("error_msg", "Please, log in to view this page");
      res.redirect("/login");
    }
  }
}
```

Nesse formato recebo o erro "Cannot GET /home"

```js
// @desc Home Page
// @route GET /home
// @acess Private
exports.getHome = (isAuth),(req, res) => {
  res.render("home", {
    name: req.user.username
  });
};
```

Alguem sabe dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Como você está importando esse novo módulo? E como está ligando-o no Express?

Comment: Ao que me parece, o erro é na hora que você exporta. Tente exportar um array: `exports.getHome = [isAuth, (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", {
    name: req.user.username
  });
}]`.

Comment: Estou importando desta forma:

const { isAuth } = require("../config/auth");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O teu problema está na sintaxe de `exports.getHome = (isAuth),(req, res) => {`. Esse `isAuth` (que é um middleware) não pode ser exportado dessa maneira.

Podias exportar uma array com essas duas funções e depois usar `app.get("/home", ...controlers)`.

Eu costumo fazer assim:

**Rotas:**

```
const {isAuth} = require('./isAuth.js');
const controllers = require('./controllers.js');
app.get("/home", isAuth, controllers.getHome);
app.get("/store", isAuth, controllers.getStore);
```

**isAuth.js:**

```
module.isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  } else {
    req.flash("error_msg", "Please, log in to view this page");
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
}
```

**controllers.js:**

```
exports.getHome = (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", {
    name: req.user.username
  });
};
exports.getStore = (req, res) => {
  res.render("store", {
    name: req.user.username,
    items: db.userItems // só um exemplo
  });
};
```

Comment: No arquivo das rotas está assim:
// Home Page
router
  .route("/home")
  .get(getHome);

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Aaaaah consegui!

Com as informações que vcs passaram fiz umas alterações e deu boa!

isAuth.js (middleware)

```js
module.exports = {
  isAuth: (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    } else {
      req.flash("error_msg", "Please, log in to view this page, yo!");
      res.redirect("/login");
    }
  }
}
```

Rotas

```js
const express = require("express");
const { getHome } = require("../controllers/users");
const { isAuth } = require("../config/auth");

// Home Page
router
  .route("/home")
  .get(isAuth, getHome);
```

users.js (Controller)

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// @desc Home Page
// @route GET /home
// @acess Private
exports.getHome = (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("home", {
    name: req.user.username
  });
};
```

:D